# To find determinant of adjoint of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to show the determinant of adjoint of n by n matrix is $n$ or $0$ or $1$. I know that $\det(adj A) =[ \det (A) ]^{(n-1)}$. I also know inverse of A in terms of $\det (A)$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of matrix is A? Over what?

Comment: Something is wrong with your problem. Take a matrix A with $dim(A)=2$ and $\det(A)=3$. This case $\det(adj (A))=3$.

Comment: Only information given about matrix A is that it is n by n matrix.

Comment: If you *really* know what you say you do, then it is *impossible* that $\;(\det A)^{n-1}=\det\,\text{Adj}\,A=0,1,n\;$ **in the general case**. Either there are conditions we're missing or else the claim is false.

Comment: I would badly like to know those missing conditions whose addition will make the claim true. Thanks

Comment: @EugenCovaci: I believe the Question is about the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) to $A$ rather than the "adjoint" or transpose of $A$.

Comment: The OP seems to have misremembered the problem. What is true is that the **rank** of the adjugate of $A$ is either $0$ or $1$ or $n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

First, the relation you say you know is true and easy to prove: we indeed have that

$$\color{red}{(**)}\;\;\;A\cdot\text{Adj}\,A=|A|\cdot I\implies |A|\cdot|\text{Adj}\,A|=|A|^n$$

so if $\;A\;$ is regular then we indeed have  $\;|\text{Adj}\,A|=|A|^{n-1}\;$ . Now, this equals $\;1,\,n\;$ iff $\;|A|^{n-1}=1,\,n\;$ , so $\;|A|\;$ must then be an $\;(n-1)\,-$ th root of $\;1\;$ or of $\;n\;$.

On the other hand, if $\;A\;$ is singular then $\;|A|=0\;$ , so from $\;(**)\;$ above we get $\;A\cdot\text{adj}\,A=0\;$ and this means $\;\text{Adj}\,A\;$ is singular, too nand thus $\;|\text{Adj}\,A|=0\;$